# How do I create an array that looks like this?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have a array.
result of print_r this array is this:

```
Array
(
    [flat_rate] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => flat_rate
            [label] => book
            [cost] => 8000
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                )

            [method_id] => flat_rate
        )

    [local_delivery] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => local_delivery
            [label] => dvd
            [cost] => 15000
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                )

            [method_id] => local_delivery
        )

)
```

I need to create array like this.
I try to this array by this code:

```
Array("flat_rate" => (object) Array("id" => "flat_rate" ,"label" => "book" ,"cost" => 8000 ,"taxes" => Array ( ) ,"method_id" => "flat_rate") ,"local_delivery" => (object) Array("id" => "local_delivery" ,"label" => "book" ,"cost" => 15000 ,"taxes" => Array ( ) ,"method_id" => "local_delivery"));
```

but when print_r this array, **WC_Shipping_Rate** change by **stdClass**

Comment: You need to call the `WC_Shipping_Rate` constructor to get that type of object.

Comment: *Why* do you need it?

Comment: I need to change array on woocommerce in wordpress

Comment: how to call WC_Shipping_Rate? :((

Comment: It's probably a good idea to take a step back and consider what it is you are actually trying to achieve - "changing the array" sounds like a solution you have come up with to a larger problem, not something you'd want to do for its own sake. This is referred to as [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand, what do you really want to do. As far as I understand you, you want to make an array with objects of instance WC_Shipping_Rate inside? If that is so, you must create a new instance of class WC_Shipping_Rate `$object = new WC_Shipping_Rate;` Then, you can just fill it and apply to your array:

```
$object = new WC_Shipping_Rate();
$object->id = 'local_delivery'; // OR with setter, if the class has it $object->setId('local_delivery');
$object->label = 'dvd';
// ...etc
$array = array(
    "flat_rate" => $object
);
```

Comment: Importantly, you need to understand what the `WC_Shipping_Rate` objects *are*, so that you can populate them in a way that the application will understand.